# How to change the field label in layout.?

Tags: page-layout

I have below scenario. Could you give me information how can I achieve it.

Scenario:

To have consistency in name I need to change the label from **Case Number** to **Case**

Below show is a screenshot of **related list** in **Contact**

How can I change the label from **Case Number** to **Case**.

NB: The **Case** and **Case Number** are same field of **Case object**.

I tried to change the label in the layout but couldn't find an option to change the label.

[image: Case-Contact-related-list]

[image: Meta-data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same effect only in this layout (according to your comment in a previous answer), an alternative solution (not relabelling technically) is to create a custom formula (Text) field with label "Case". Then drag and drop it to the layout. The formula is

```
HYPERLINK('/' + Id , CaseNumber, '_self')
```

The following screenshot proves it:

[image: case number solution]

Don't think you can relabel the field in a particular layout.

Answer (score 2):

To change the labels for Standard Objects and Fields in Salesforce, simply go to Setup -> Rename Tabs and Labels. Then choose the Object you want to rename and click Edit. Change the singular and plural labels if required or for your case you simply click Next button to change labels for the Standard Fields and save.

Comment: But Night Guy, I don't want it to affect other places. I want the changes only in this layout.

Comment: @ABHINB.T You can't have the field label renamed for one (or few) page layouts only. Consider using a lightning record page (instead of page layout) and use a custom component to display the related list (you can code the feature to have label renamed in this custom component).

Comment: @ABHINB.T Another approach is to create formula field that simply copies the case number field values. Name this formula field with the preferred label and use it wherever needed. However, I would discourage using this approach for large data volume objects and its over usage. Reason being that this approach would likely surface performance issues associated with having formula fields in the long run.